# Return to lldb prompt when debugging interactive command-line program

Tags: lldb

I'm debugging an interactive, command-line program with `lldb`. The program  presents its own prompt to the user (in a manner similar to `fdisk`).

My question is, how do I escape, or get back to, the `lldb` prompt while I'm executing the program?

Here's how I go about launching the program and getting to the point that I'm inquiring about:

```
bash$ lldb progname progarg1
(lldb) target create "progname"
Current executable set to 'progname' (x86_64).
(lldb) settings set -- target.run-args "progarg1"
(lldb) process launch
Process launched Process 29286 launched: '/home/chb/progdir/progname' (x86_64)
progname>help
Commands are:
    buy:   use schmeckles to buy a plumbus
    lube:  rub with the fleeb
    ...
progname>
```

After entering the program's command loop, how do I get back to `lldb` to issue other, `lldb`-related commands?

Comment: If you are debugging a program that makes heavy use of the Terminal, it's often more convenient to give it its own terminal.  Just open another terminal window, note the device - you can get Terminal.app to print the TTY, then when you launch the program (/dev/ttys001 or some such) pass this to the --tty option.  Then you don't have to worry about the output from the two getting intermixed.

Comment: @JimIngham This is solid comment gold. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting Control-C on your keyboard interrupts the program and lldb takes control.